# How can I make Array of Structure in NSIS

Tags: nsis

I have an XML file....Now I want to Parse it and store data into Array of structure as per my requirement in NSIS SCRIPT.

```
  This is my XML:-

  <?xml version="1.0" ?> 
- <request>
- <software>
  <id>1</id> 
  <name>software</name> 
  <description>is a file archiver with a high compression ratio.</description> 
  <download_url>http://surfnet.dl.sourceforge.net/project/sevenzip/7-Zip/9.20/7z920.exe</download_url> 
  <image_url>http://assets.airinstaller.com/graphics/software/7zip/left_side.bmp</image_url> 
  </software>
- <offers>
- <offer>
  <rank>1</rank> 
- <options>
- <option>
 <text>Install Facemoods1</text> 
  <value>/TOOLBAR</value> 
  <required>true</required> 
  </option>
- <option>
  <text>Set Facemoods as my default search provider1</text> 
  <value>/DEFAULTSEARCH</value> 
  <required>false</required> 
  </option>
  </options>
  <install_location>{pf}/IssPro c.dll</install_location> 
   <name>1</name> 
  <tagline>The Ringtone Maker</tagline> 
  <description>makes creating ringtones really easy.</description> 
  <exe_cmd /> 
  <download_url>http://174.36.153.163/silent-ringtonejunkiez-installer.exe</download_url> 
  <conversion_url>http://api.airinstaller.com/get/installed.php?session=9649922a0d879d92752f3925e07153c3&app=2&aff=1&off=1</conversion_url> 
     <image_url>http://assets.airinstaller.com/graphics/offers/ringtonejunkiez/logo.bmp</image_url> 
  <privacy_url>http://www.google.com/intl/en/privacy/privacy-policy.html</privacy_url> 
  <terms_url>http://www.google.com/accounts/TOS</terms_url> 
  </offer>
- <offer>
  <rank>2</rank> 
- <options>
- <option>
  <text>Install Facemoods</text> 
  <value>/TOOLBAR</value> 
  <required>true</required> 
  </option>
- <option>
  <text>Set Facemoods as my default search provider</text> 
  <value>/DEFAULTSEARCH</value> 
  <required>false</required> 
  </option>
- <option>
  <text>Set Facemoods as my default home and new tab page</text> 
  <value>/DEFAULTSTART</value> 
  <required>false</required> 
  </option>
  </options>
  <name>Ringtone 2</name> 
  <tagline>The Ringtone Maker</tagline> 
  <description>makes creating ringtones really easy.</description> 
   <exe_cmd /> 
  <download_url>http://174.36.153.163/silent-ringtonejunkiez-installer.exe</download_url> 
  <conversion_url>http://api.airinstaller.com/get/installed.php?session=9649922a0d879d92752f3925e07153c3&app=2&aff=1&off=1</conversion_url> 
   <image_url>http://assets.airinstaller.com/graphics/offers/ringtonejunkiez/logo.bmp</image_url> 
   <privacy_url>http://www.google.com/intl/en/privacy/privacy-policy.html</privacy_url> 
   <terms_url>http://www.google.com/accounts/TOS</terms_url> 
  </offer>
- <offer>
  <rank>3</rank> 
  <id>13</id> 
  <install_location>{pf}/Real/RealPlayer/f ixrjb.exe</install_location> 
  <name>3</name> 
  <description>makes creating ringtones really easy.</description> 
  <exe_cmd /> 
  <download_url>http://174.36.153.163/silent-ringtonejunkiez-installer.exe</download_url> 
  <conversion_url>http://api.airinstaller.com/get/installed.php?session=9649922a0d879d92752f3925e07153c3&app=2&aff=1&off=1</conversion_url> 
   <image_url>http://assets.airinstaller.com/graphics/offers/ringtonejunkiez/logo.bmp</image_url> 
   <privacy_url>http://www.google.com/intl/en/privacy/privacy-policy.html</privacy_url> 
   <terms_url>http://www.google.com/accounts/TOS</terms_url> 
   </offer>
   </offers>
   </request>
```

Please Anyone help me to Parse it and Store into array of Structures in NSIS Script...

I am badly stucked here....

Thanks for reply but I did not get this.......
I have parsed the XML with this method

```
${XML::GotoPath} "/request/software" $0 

        ${XML::NextSiblingElement} "" $0 $1
                        DetailPrint "Next Sibling Element of Root Element=$0"          ; SIBLING OF SOFTWARE (SECOND CHILD OF ROOT)


           ${XML::XPathString} "count(//offer)" $0 $1
           StrCpy $ccount_offer $0
             ;${If} $0 != ""
           ; IntOp $count_offer $count_offer + 1
            ; DetailPrint "Count= $0 and $count_offer"
           ;Goto for
            ;${Else}
           ;Goto next
           ;${EndIf}


   ${For} $R1 1 $ccount_offer
         ${If} $R1 == 1
           ${XML::FirstChildElement} "" $0 $1
                 DetailPrint "Element in Offers=$0"                                ; FIRST ElEMENT    IN OFFERS
           ${xml::ElementPath} $0
     StrCpy $ccurrent_path $0
         ${Else}
           ${XML::NextSiblingElement} "" $0 $1
           DetailPrint "Element in offer=$0"
             ${xml::ElementPath} $0
     StrCpy $ccurrent_path $0
                ${EndIf}

          ${XML::XPathString} "count(child::*)" $0 $1
          ;DetailPrint "count======$0"
     StrCpy $ccount_offer_child  $0
       ${XML::FirstChildElement} "" $0 $1                       ;first child of offer
      DetailPrint "Element in Offer=$0"
          ${XML::GetText} $0 $1
     DetailPrint "Text in it=$0"
       IntOp $ccount_offer_child $ccount_offer_child - 1
  ${For} $R2 1 $ccount_offer_child

            ;${If} $R2 == 1


       ;${Else}

          ${XML::NextSiblingElement} "" $0 $1
     DetailPrint "Element in Offer=$0"


           ${If} $0 == "options"                                  ; options for loops


             ${xml::ElementPath} $0
       StrCpy $llast_current_path $0

          ${XML::XPathString} "count(child::*)" $0 $1
          StrCpy $ccount_options  $0

    ${If} $0 != 0

    ${For} $R3 1 $ccount_options
         ${If} $R3 == 1
          ${XML::FirstChildElement} "" $0 $1
        DetailPrint "Element in Options=$0"

          ${xml::ElementPath} $0
          StrCpy $llast_last_current_path $0


          ${XML::XPathString} "count(child::*)" $0 $1
          StrCpy $ccount_options_option  $0

      ${For} $R4 1 $ccount_options_option
            ${If} $R4 == 1

         ${XML::FirstChildElement} "" $0 $1
     DetailPrint "Element in Option=$0"

  ${XML::GetText} $0 $1
          DetailPrint "Text in it=$0"
          ${Else}

         ${XML::NextSiblingElement} "" $0 $1
     DetailPrint "Element in Option=$0"

 ${XML::GetText} $0 $1
         DetailPrint "Text in it=$0"

${EndIf}


    ${Next}



         ${XML::GotoPath} $llast_last_current_path $0

${Else}

      ${XML::GotoPath} $llast_last_current_path $0

        ${XML::NextSiblingElement} "" $0 $1
      DetailPrint "Element in Options=$0"

          ${XML::XPathString} "count(child::*)" $0 $1
         StrCpy $ccount_options_option  $0

  ${For} $R4 1 $ccount_options_option
          ${If} $R4 == 1

        ${XML::FirstChildElement} "" $0 $1
      DetailPrint "Element in Option=$0"

  ${XML::GetText} $0 $1
         DetailPrint "Text in it=$0"

           ${Else}

        ${XML::NextSiblingElement} "" $0 $1
     DetailPrint "Element in Option=$0"

 ${XML::GetText} $0 $1
         DetailPrint "Text in it=$0"

    ${EndIf}

${Next}

         ${EndIf}




${Next}

   ${EndIf}
                 ${XML::GotoPath} $llast_current_path $0          ;end of options      for loops


     ${ElseIf} $0 == "exe_cmd"
     ${Else}
     ${XML::GetText} $0 $1
     DetailPrint "Text in it=$0"
         ${EndIf}

        ; ${EndIf}

${Next}

        ${XML::GotoPath} "$ccurrent_path" $0

${Next}
```

Now I want the data to be stored into Array of structure not in simply array.......because the XML is dynamic and the size(tags) can be increased so I think to store data into array of structure(not alone array) will be better aproach.....

Comment: *Why* do you need to store the XML? Start by assuming you don't. What do you want to get out of it? What do you intend to use it for? Why is it XML? (Can you have it in a format like INI which is easy to work with?)

Comment: Stop there! *You do not need to know that yet.* First of all, explain *why* you need it. I don't believe you do need it: another way of accessing it will probably be better. Focus on the problem, not the means you have in mind of solving it, which isn't possible in NSIS.

Comment: I want to know can we make array of structure in Nsis like in c/c++ if yes then how can we make it??

Comment: *You are asking the wrong question.* Please reread my earlier two comments.

Comment: I am making dynamic Installer in which first of all it sends request to URL which sends back the XML in response from there i have to fetch the data and store it after that i have to show it on custom pages one by one like the offer tags data only one offer on one page.......So the problem coming is that how to store the data so that i can easily use it later on and there is one another problem also that we don't know the number of offer tags in the XML they can be 2 or 5 or may be 10 also....So what is the better approach to store data???

Comment: OK, so you do genuinely ned to deal with XML. My primary recommendation would be to just save the XML file and then just use the XML plugin directly on it. Don't worry about trying to save it into an array.

Comment: It will be not a good way because if the user presses Next button twice or more than deadlock may occur....

Comment: That is not at all a possibility; it is not possible to click the Next button twice, for it is all single-threaded; the single-threadedness of it also precludes any possibility of deadlock inside the script itself (deadlock requires two streams of execution to be possible).

Answer (score 1):

NSIS does not have native support for arrays but you can use one of the alternatives listed [here](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Arrays_in_NSIS).

Comment: Thanks for Reply....But my Problem is How to make array of structure and Secondly store Whole XML data into it.....

Answer (score 1):

At first you need to parse the data from XML with some XML plug-in (like this: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/XML_plug-in).

Then save your data in array with some http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Arrays_in_NSIS plug-in (nsArray plug-in is recommended).

Do you want to save whole tree in array? I suppose this is really tough task because there are many possibilities: do you want to save all elements or only non empty ones?
Or you simply want to read some values?

Please be more specific how the array should look like.

Edit: (Example)

Simply traverse your loaded tree in a loop and save data:

```
  IntOp $R1 0 + 0 ; Set $R1 to zero at beginning

  ${While} End_Of_XML_Tree

    ; Fill $your_value with the data you want (element name, value or even whole node path)

    nsArray::Set your_array /key=$R1 $your_value ; Save value to your_array at key = $R1
    IntOp $R1 $R1 + 1 ; Increase $R1 (next key)
  ${EndWhile}
```

nsArray::Set adds `value` at `key`, replacing any existing value with that key.

Comment: Thanks for Reply....But my Problem is How to make array of structure and Secondly store Whole XML data into it.....I have parsed it using XML plugins and now I need Whole data to be stored 
into array of structure......